# Power Automate Trigger Condition when a file is uploaded inside a specific folder and get the main folder ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, folder, power-platform

I have a SharePoint online site which contain a document library named "Customer Share" >> and inside this library we have a folder named "Clients" >> and inside the "Clients" folder we have around 10,000 sub-folders representing clients.

Here is a sample of the folder structure:-

- Customer share

  - Clients

    - ClientA

      - Contracts
      - Agrements
      - others
    - ClientB

      - Contracts
      - others
    - ClientC
    - ClientD
  - Attachments
  - others

Now I want to define a trigger condition for our power automate flow, when a document is created or modified ONLY under the clients sub-folders.

For example, to ONLY trigger the flow if someone add a file under "Clients/ClientA/Contracts" or under "Clients/ClientA/" or under "/Clients/ClientA/Contracts/2023/". While the flow should not run if someone add or modify a file under "/Attachments/" or "others" or directly under "/Clients" .Is this possible?

Second Question. I also need to get the Folder ID of the related client sub-folder. For example if a file is uploaded inside "/Clients/ClientA/Contracts/2023/" >>  then I want to get the ID of the ClientA folder.

Thanks